# nm versus gdb break

Tags: gdb, virtual-address-space, nm

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have an executable file `exec` compiled from `file.c`. The `file.c` makes use of functions from a static library. For example, let's says that `fubar()` is a function of the static library that is used in `file.c`.
This is something that I have noticed.

- `nm exec | grep fubar` gives a certain value.
  (on my system and for my executable, `0808377f`)
- `gdb ./exec` and then `break fubar` gives a different value.
  (on my system and for my executable, `0x8083785`)

When I do a similar thing for another executable file (`exec1` compiled from `file1.c`, it outputs the same value for both the commands).

Both the commands are supposed to output the same virtual address. Aren't they? I am obviously missing something. Can someone explain what exactly is happening? And what is the difference between both the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring unusual things like `-fPIE`, what is going on here is that the gdb command `break function` actually means "break after the function prologue for `function`".  This way, arguments are set up properly by the time the breakpoint is hit.

If you want to break exactly at the first instruction of a function, use the `*` syntax, like:

```
(gdb) break *function
```

If you do this the addresses will probably match.